# Search someones followers on twitter

Tags: twitter

I met someone at a concert but I didn't get their contact info. All I really know is their first name and I am definitely sure they are following a band on Twitter.

Is there anyway to get a list of all the followers, so I can just manually search that for the name? There has to be a better way than loading 20 people at a time.

Comment: When you say "following a band on facebook" do you mean twitter? Are those two things just unrelated?

Comment: Related: [How do I download a complete list for all the followers of a twitter account?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27300/how-do-i-download-a-complete-list-of-followers-for-a-twitter-account)

Comment: I meant twitter

Answer (score 4):

Try [Followerwonk](https://followerwonk.com/). If the band has fewer than a certain number of followers, you will be able to search through the bio information of all followers for free.

1. Sign in
2. Click "Analyze Followers"
3. Enter the band's Twitter handle
4. Click "View All"
5. and then sort by the relevant info ie. "Real name"

There are several other third-party Twitter apps that provide similar services.

Comment: Definitely easier than downloading an exhaustive list!

Comment: That'll only work if you're a subscriber on Followerwonk.